# Как автоматически обновлять страницу?

Tags: google-chrome, браузер, расширения

Как в браузере Google Chrome организовать автоматическое обновление страницы с некоторой **периодичностью**? Скажем, есть информация, которая обновится при обновлении страницы, но не сама. Возможно, есть какое-то расширение, как оно называется?

Comment: [Page Refresh](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/page-refresh/hmooaemjmediafeacjplpbpenjnpcneg?hl=ru), например

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В php можно добавить `header("Refresh:0");` код примерно такой `header("Refresh: $sec; url=$page");`

Если страница не ваша то ищите auto reloader [к примеру](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/easy-auto-refresh/aabcgdmkeabbnleenpncegpcngjpnjkc)

Comment: Да я вначале, удалил сообщение, но потом докинул ссылку на расширенее.